# Scroll в конец страницы при нажатии на <button>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый Вечер! Интересует такой вопрос, существует ли JS функция которая при нажатии на клавишу button, делает скролл в конец страницы спустя 1 секунду? 
Код кнопки:

```html
<button type="submit" class="wrapper_input" style="right: 42px;position: relative;top: 1px;">
<img src="../static/assets/plus.svg" id="OnBottom" height="30" title="Aggiungi candidato" alt="Aggiungi candidato" style="visibility: visible;">
</button>
```

Так же начало прокручиваемого DIV при нажатии на кнопку:

```html
<div class="main_content">
</div>
```

В моем случае это выглядит так: я добавляю контакт на своем сайте, он оказывается внизу моей страницы, и мне нужно делать скролл что бы увидеть его. По этому и задался таким вопросом решения проблемы со скроллом вниз страницы, спустя 1 секунду при нажатии на кнопку "добавить".

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let body = document.body;
body.querySelector(".wrapper_input").addEventListener("click",()=>setTimeout(()=>body.scrollTop = body.scrollHeight,1000));
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="wrapper_input" style="right: 42px;position: relative;top: 1px;">
  <img src="../static/assets/plus.svg" id="OnBottom" height="30" title="Aggiungi candidato" alt="Aggiungi candidato" style="visibility: visible;">
</button>
```